# How to display the selected row from the database to a modal once a button in asp repeater has been clicked? ASP C#

Tags: asp.net, asprepeater

> I am trying to make a table where in it shows the data from the database and once you click on the view details button, a modal or pop-up will appear. This modal or pop will contain the details of the selected row
>   This is the code in ASP.net.

```
     <HeaderTemplate>
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Order ID
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Customer Name
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Order Details
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Order Status
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Action
                    </th>
                </tr>
                    </thead>
        </HeaderTemplate>

        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>
         <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"OrderID").ToString()%>
                </td>
                    <td>
         <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"CustomerName").ToString() %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
         <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"OrderDetails").ToString()%>
                    </td>
                    <td>
         <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"OrderStatus").ToString()%>
                    </td>   


                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="lbl_View" runat="server" Text="View Details" /></td>


            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

> This is the code behind. Once the view details button has been clicked I want to display a modal that displays all the data in the selected row from the database

```
  protected void lbl_View_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```